# Why is the Galois group of the polynomial $f(x)=x^5-x-1$ isomorphic to $S_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, galois-theory

Currently I am trying to understand why quintic (and higher degree) polynomials are not soluble by radicals, and one of the easiest examples of a quintic polynomial which has a nonsoluble Galois group, $S_5$, is the polynomial $f(x)=x^5-x-1$. Could someone please explain to me why this polynomial's Galois group is isomorphic to $S_5$?

Comment: Over what field?

Comment: Help us help you, what can you say about this polynomial? Is it irreducible (over which field by the way?) ? How many real roots does this polynomial have ?

Comment: This polynomial has 1 real root and 3 complex. It is over field Q (the rationals)

Comment: See [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?rep=rep1&type=pdf&doi=10.1.1.211.2314), Example 3.33.

Comment: Every complex root must have a complex conjugate one, it cannot have only 3 complex roots.